# Change the sub module value on the basis of parent module checkbox in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-material

### If i change the value of switch button to false , then change the value of all submodule to false

```
<div class="content">
  <md-slide-toggle color="primary" [(ngModel)]="permission.permission.department.main" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">On/Off</md-slide-toggle>
</div>
<div *ngIf="permission.permission.department.main" class="content">
    <md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="permission.permission.department.view" align="end" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">View</md-checkbox>
    <md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="permission.permission.department.add" align="end" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">Add</md-checkbox>
    <md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="permission.permission.department.edit" align="end" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">Edit</md-checkbox>
    <md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="permission.permission.department.delete" align="end" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">Delete</md-checkbox>    
</div>
```

Comment: what problem you are facing ?

Comment: if md-slide-toggle value false then all checkbox values should also set to false

Answer (score 0):

You can update value on change function please check and let me know if you want somthing else

```
<md-slide-toggle color="primary" 
[(ngModel)]="permission.permission.department.main" 
(change)="setValue(permission.permission.department.main,permission.permission.department)" 
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">On/Off</md-slide-toggle>
```

in your ts file add a method

```
setValue(currentvalue,p){
for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    p[key]=currentvalue;
  }
}
}
```